# jQuery fengyuanchen cropper plugin - getImageData() cannot get width/height

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop

I am using [fengyuanchen jQuery cropper](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper)

I have the cropper set to be responsive. This means that the displayed width/height of the image being cropped may not be the true native width/height. I need to get the displayed width/height so that I can calculate where to crop the original full-size image when applicable.

I read this example in [the docs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper):

```
var imageData = $().cropper('getImageData');
```

However, `console.log(imageData);` returns this:

```
> n.fn.init {}
    > __proto__ : Object[0]
        /* Inside this is every custom defined js function */
```

If anyone has experience with this it would be a major help.

**For anyone else with this issue**:
I'm currently just grabbing the `.width()` of the `.cropper-canvas` object like this, but I would still appreciate if someone knew how to use the method properly.

```
var cropperCanvas = $('.cropper-canvas');
console.log('Width: '+cropperCanvas.width()+"\nHeight:"+cropperCanvas.height());
```

Answer (score 0):

To access this information you must call these methods inside the 'built' function. Like so:

```js
var $crop = $('.img');

$crop.cropper({
  built: function() {
    var canvasData = $crop.cropper('getCanvasData');
    var cropBoxData = $crop.cropper('getCropBoxData');
    var imageData = $crop.cropper('getImageData');
    
    $('.cd').text('Canvas Data: ' + JSON.stringify(canvasData));
    $('.cb').text('CropBox Data: ' + JSON.stringify(cropBoxData));
    $('.id').text('Image Data: ' + JSON.stringify(imageData));
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
}

.container .img {
  width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.4/cropper.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="http://www.beijingiphonerepair.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/iphone4s_sample_photo_1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<p class="cd"></p>
<p class="cb"></p>
<p class="id"></p>
```

It's a simple example just to show you the idea. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issues, not much help anywhere. Pieced together a solution from various places. Documentation/real-world examples of this plugin are sadly lacking, yet it's probably the best cropper script I've used

The form:

```
<div class="cropperOriginal">
    <img id="image" src="/yourimage.jpg">
</div>
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
    X: <input type="text" name="dataX" id="dataX" placeholder="X" value="" />
    Y: <input type="text" name="dataY" id="dataY" placeholder="Y" value="" />
    W: <input type="text" name="dataWidth" id="dataWidth" placeholder="width" value="" />
    H: <input type="text" name="dataHeight" id="dataHeight" placeholder="height" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<div class="img-preview"></div>
```

The javascript

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var ele = $("#image");
    var dataX = document.getElementById('dataX');
    var dataY = document.getElementById('dataY');
    var dataHeight = document.getElementById('dataHeight');
    var dataWidth = document.getElementById('dataWidth');

    ele.cropper({
        aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
        preview: '.img-preview',
        crop: function (e) {
            var imageData = ele.cropper('getData');
            dataX.value = Math.round(imageData.left);
            dataY.value = Math.round(imageData.top);
            dataHeight.value = Math.round(imageData.height);
            dataWidth.value = Math.round(imageData.width);
        },
        zoomable: false,
        scalable: false,
        movable: false,
        background: true,
        viewMode: 2

    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone